# Proving pairwise independence given that 3 events are three-way independent but not necessarily mutually independent

Tags: probability

Some similar questions have been asked before but none answer my question adequately.

We have three events which are three-way independent:

$$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$$

I need to show that $A$ and $B \cap C$ are independent, that is:
$$P(A \cap (B \cap C)) = P(A)P(B \cap C)$$

Which means I need to show that:
$$P(B \cap C) = P(B)P(C)$$ which is pairwise independence.

Is it possible to show this simply from the first relation above, without assuming mutual independence of A,B,C?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't true.

Consider the toss a pair of fair, distinct, dice.

Let $A$ be the event:  "The first die comes up $1,2$ or $3$

Let $B$ be the event:   "The first die comes up $3,4$ or $5$."

Let $C$ be the event: " The sum of the values shown is $9$"

Then $A\cap B\cap C$ is equivalent to the toss $(3,6)$, hence it has probability $\frac 1{36}$

We compute that:

$$P(A)=\frac 12 \quad P(B)=\frac 12\quad P(C)=\frac 4{36}\implies P(A)P(B)P(C)=\frac 1{36}$$

So we have the three way independence you wanted.

However, the events are clearly not pairwise independent.  Indeed, $B\cap C$ consists of the tosses $(3,6),(4,5), (5,4)$ hence $$P(B\cap C)=\frac 3{36}\neq \frac 12\times \frac 4{36}=P(B)P(C)$$

More obviously, $A\cap C$ consists of the toss $(3,6)$ but $P(A)P(C)=\frac 1{18}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the intersection-product equation hold for three events but not hold for any pair.

Let $S$ = {$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$} with each outcome equally likely.

Let $A$ = {$1,2,3,4$}, $B$={$2,3,4,5$}, $C$={$4,6,7,8$}.

Then $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 1/2$  and

$P$($A$ & $B$ & $C$) = $P$({$4$}) $= 1/8 = P(A)P(B)P(C)$

but none of the pairwise intersections has probability $1/4$ (i.e. none has size $2$)